# Graph with 100+ edges per vertex

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, arangodb, titan, janusgraph

I'm doing some research on graph databases to see if they would fit my use case. Right now I'm looking at Janusgraph, but have also looked at ArangoDB and Neo4J a little.

I have a tree of nodes, but I was thinking of encoding version information in the edges, to create a sort of versioned database. For a given version, a traversal following the edges with that version specifier would output the correct version of that tree. This would produce a tree with `n` vertices but `100` (ish) edges per vertex (100n total).

Would there be any performance hit on traversal? Assume that there are indexes on vertexes (and edges, if that is relevant)

Comment: A "hit" on performance from what? What variables are you concerned about? With any graph database, as the number of edges increases or the complexity in evaluating an edge increases, the performance is likely to be impacted. If your "order of magnitude" is in the 100's and not the 100M's I wouldn't be too concerned but that would depend on the required/desired response time.

Comment: I was trying to see where performance would break down. I know there's this concept of a super node, but it's not clear where that delineation is. The traversals would commonly be of the kind where you get all the child vertices of a certain vertex, and record the path being traversed.

Comment: Full disclosure: I am an object and graph database software engineer for Objectivity, Inc. We market a massively scalable object/graph database. Depending on how you navigate a graph to build result path that matches your criteria, supernodes can be an issue. In any implementation, a node will have some kind of list of edges emanating from a node. That implementation will largely drive the efficiency by which the proper subset of edges will be selected from the available set of edges. If you are in the 100 (ish) range most implementations will probably support what you want to do.